# How can many faces be mapped to a texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

A tree model with leaves looks like (created by sapling addon):

[image]

Using unwrap and reset shows orientation issues like a leaves stem pointing to the outside instead of the branch.

[image]

Before UV reset the UV-map shows this pattern, some leave pairs are upright and some are rotated by 90°.

[image: I tried various selection methods with s]

How should all the UV islands be rotated to match the images orientation? Is there a method that is less time consuming than manual select and transform?

I tried almost all options from *Mesh* / *Select* / *Similar* to unwrap at least the upright and rotated pairs of faces separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to switch your leave settings from Hexoganol to Rectangular. This will make single planes without cuts (extra edges) with 1 origin and it will unwrap as a single plane (like resetting the uv map). It is then easier to make adjustments for the direction of the leaves and will effect all the leaves in the same way (from the root). I don't know of any other workflow's for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be not to use the leaves created by the sapling add-on. Instead create a leave and set the origin to the end of the stem:

[image]

Weight paint allows also to control where the hair particles should appear:

[image]

Particle settings:

[image]